# Rewrite live site front-end to subfolder (but not /admin) and nothing on localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Lots of info nearly solves this, but nothing will quite crack it yet.

The site has a front-end (all in root basically), and an admin panel living in `/admin`. Basic stuff.

The site runs remotely on http://www.example.com and locally on http://foo

I want nothing **locally** redirected at all.

On the **live server** I just want *front-end* traffic redirected to a sub-folder `/coming_soon` but no redirection on the admin panel. So the client can start work in admin, but the public will only ever see the content in `/coming_soon`. (Plus I guess the admin login page, but that's fine).

Closest I came was:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=foo
  RewriteRule ^$ /coming_soon [L]
</IfModule>
```

But that let me hit the "real" front-end by browsing directly to http://www.example.com/index.php

Your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I got your question right^^ Wasn't sure about the /admin part, who should access or if possible no one or...But the following is my take on your problem:

```
RewriteEngine On

#excludes HOST=foo and URI=/admin from rewrite to /coming_soon
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^foo [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/coming_soon [R=301,L]
```

You can additionally set a location-directive and only allow entering /admin from specific IP(s).

```
<location /admin>
    required ip 10.11.12.13
    required ip 20.30.40.0/24
</location>
```

---

**update**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(coming_soon|admin)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /coming_soon [R=302,L]
```

And R=302 is just temporary rewrite = won't be cached by browsers with target location. R=301 would tell browsers to save the target `/coming_soon` right away.

Comment: Thanks for that. It did not quite work, but got me on the right track. I'll post as an answer what worked for me... Everyone can access admin, local or remote.

Comment: Ah, k. I thought no one but you should be able to access admin ;) will leave my answer as it is, because I think there will be more people searching for a version without access to a specific location like `/admin`. But will also add a simplified version of the working answer as **update**.

Comment: The update cracked it, and is more elegant than my answer, so you win :) Thanks very much. You'd think this would be a fairly widely used snippet, but I couldn't find it anywhere. The short story is it lets me work locally on the whole site, lets the end client start using his admin panel right away, but sends front end traffic to coming soon for a while. Very useful :)

Comment: Thanks^^ Glad I was able to help ;) Your vote pushed me over 500 rep, was waiting all day for that to happen :D And yes, useful indeed, although I never had use for it :)

Answer (score 0):

...if any one can improve this, or make it more elegant, I'd love to hear!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/coming_soon
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /coming_soon [R=302,R]
```